# Disable check boxes under the main div jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <div class="ex" id="baseTypes">
                            <table>
                                <tr>

                                <?php foreach ($transTypeList as $list) {
                                ?><tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="chkTransTypeBsn" style="vertical-align:baseline" name="chkTransTypeBsn[]" type="checkbox"   value="<?php echo $list->trn_typ_code; ?>"  />
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="100px;">

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="chkBsnPreivous" style="vertical-align:baseline" name="chkBsnPreivous" type="checkbox"   value="1"  />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                            ?>

                            <?php
                                    }
                            ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

This is  my code i want to disabled all the checkboxes onclick buttoon

my jquery is not working up to now any help

```
var checked = $("#ChkIsbsTxn").attr("checked");
                if(checked){
                   $("#baseTypes : input").attr("disabled", true);
                }else{
                    $("#baseTypes : input").attr("disabled", false);
                }
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? There are different ways to select checked inputs in different versions. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var checked = $("#ChkIsbsTxn").attr("checked");
if(checked){
    $("#baseTypes input").attr("disabled", true);
}else{
    $("#baseTypes input").removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery 1.6 you can do:

```
$("#baseTypes input:checkbox").attr("disabled", $("#ChkIsbsTxn").is(":checked"));
```

In older versions you would do

```
if($("#ChkIsbsTxn:checked").length){
    $("#baseTypes input:checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // Disable
}else{
    $("#baseTypes input:checkbox").remove("disabled"); // Enable    
}
```